# Learning CSS on HTML

Tags: html, css

I've been learned some techniques of CSS for a little while, i kinda confused which website i should to use for learning CSS well. I search on google which one is good for CSS full tutorials, but no one is perfect for me. So, what is the website(s) which good for learning CSS on HTML from beginning? I mean, such as the website full with tutorials plus explanations (except w3schools). Thanks for your answers

Comment: http://www.codecademy.com/learn is a great resource for this kind of thing, specifically the [HTML and CSS course](http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/web).

Comment: @Muhammad Agdha, you need to make your question more specific, practical, detailed, etc.  Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/tour and maybe you can improve your question.

Comment: HeadFirst books are also a great way to learn.  http://www.headfirstlabs.com/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please be sure to read our [ask] page to help you formulate a great question.  You are much more likely to get a good answer from the community if you put some effort into your question.

Comment: @Nick Bartlett: Thanks, it's very helpful

Comment: @bn: Sorry about that, i didn't really good yet to ask questions, but i'll try my best.

Comment: @ochi: I'll read that, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I love [codecademy.com](http://codecademy.com), and used it to learn HTML, CSS, Javascript, JQuery, and Ruby. It is a very comprehensive lesson, and teaches you how to USE the language, and the syntax, and from there it's a simple matter to look up extra styling attributes as needed